# 12V boat lead acid battery suddenly failed

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, 12v, lead-acid, solar-charge-controller

Battery on boat and powered by solar panels started acting really weird suddenly exactly a week ago. App shows voltage went from minimum 12.3V to min 6V in a day. On board voltmeter showing 11.9-12.2 ish when it’s usually much higher, and only up to 13.4 ish when charging with engine when usually 14+.

Just checked and Victron controller is showing float rather than bulk.

The batteries were charged with the engine for several hours with no change in reading. Any ideas what most likely problem is?

No change in usage amount or weather (solar gain). Batteries are under a year old and I take care to never let them get below 12.4V ish.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked all the connections to be sure they're tight and there's no corrosion?

Comment: @Hearth The post says that the batteries are under a year old.

Comment: @JohnD I completely missed that, oops.

Comment: 14+ seems a tad high for sustainer charging.  How often do you check water level in these batteries?   If the charger were running a tad high, in my experience that could easy "boil" off enough water to uncover the plates.

Comment: Rare as it is, sometimes batteries are defective.  After checking the contacts and finding no solution,  if new enough to still be under warranty, go exchange them out.

Comment: _"Batteries are under a year old and I take care to never let them get below 12.4v ish"_ - there is more than 1 battery?

Comment: A 12 V lead acid battery has 6 cells, it looks like one cell is shorted. If the connections between the cells are accessible, the individual cell voltages may be measured and compared. But the voltage of all cells looks like there is more than one bad cell.